# setTime 0 on each video on ended

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 or 4 modules like this in each page.
(class "boxvideo1" and id "boxvideo4" are added by js)

```
    <div class="servicios__layout">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="box boxvideo1">
          <video id="boxvideo4" class="slider-video h" width="100%" style="visibility: visible; width: 100%;">
            <source src="//dl.dropbox.com/s/931244iox7i0fpk/working-with-espresso.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                  </video>
            <div class="icon-play"></div>
            <a href="https://google.es"><div class="icon-mas"></div></a>                  
        </div>
        <div class="box boxvideo2">
          <video id="boxvideo4" class="slider-video h" width="100%" style="visibility: visible; width: 100%;">
            <source src="//dl.dropbox.com/s/931244iox7i0fpk/working-with-espresso.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                  </video>
            <div class="icon-play"></div>
            <a href="https://google.es"><div class="icon-mas"></div></a>                  
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I have 2 issues in the js:

- The fisrt 1 its, the tag ID always its the same and its not dynamic. (Always is boxvideo4)
- The second issue its js dont set currentTime to 0.

```
var i = 1;
var str1 = 'boxvideo';
var str2 = '.boxvideo';
var str3 = 'boxvideo';

$('.servicios__layout .box').each(function (index, value) {

  var classAdd = str1 + i;
  var classCall = str2 + i;
  var classCall2 = str3 + i;

  $(this).addClass(classAdd);
  $('.servicios__layout .box .slider-video').attr('id', classCall2);

  $(classCall + ' .slider-video').on("ended", function () {
    $(classCall + " .icon-play").fadeIn();
    document.getElementById('classCall2').currentTime = 0;
  });

  i++;
});
```

Comment: HTML Syntax requires each ID be unique; they should not be the same.

Comment: @Twisty I think the OP is saying this script which sets the id, is not setting it properly

Comment: @Taplar Yes thats correct. I dont know whats going on

Comment: @Taplar totally agree yet that code  / info is not included in the post. So no way to know or offer a fix.

Comment: @taplar Sorry i think now its complete

Comment: `getElementById('classCall2')` <-- um that is a string, not a variable reference....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  var videos = $(".slider-video");
  videos.each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).attr("id", "box-video-" + (i + 1));
  });
  videos.on("ended", function() {
    $(this).get(0).currentTime = 0;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="servicios__layout">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="box boxvideo1">
      <video id="boxvideo4" class="slider-video h" width="100%" style="visibility: visible; width: 100%;">
        <source src="//dl.dropbox.com/s/931244iox7i0fpk/working-with-espresso.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
      <div class="icon-play"></div>
      <a href="https://google.es">
        <div class="icon-mas"></div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="box boxvideo2">
      <video id="boxvideo4" class="slider-video h" width="100%" style="visibility: visible; width: 100%;">
        <source src="//dl.dropbox.com/s/931244iox7i0fpk/working-with-espresso.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
      <div class="icon-play"></div>
      <a href="https://google.es">
        <div class="icon-mas"></div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

To reset the `id` within your Loop, I would use variables passed in to your callback function. I used `i` for Index, and `el` for the Element.

> The `.each()` method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword this refers to the element.

See more: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: But i think if i put 50 videos and i play 3, i will have a issue

Comment: Thx! The code `$(this).get(0).currentTime = 0;` solve my issue when finish. But my 1º issue its my code doesnt add a dynamic ID to the video with `$('.servicios__layout .box .slider-video').attr('id', classCall2);`.

Comment: @Jose you did not post how the Code that generates the content. Not sure how to help without that.

Comment: Its a simple HTML code just how the example but with 4 or 5 "box" inside the grid. I generate the content manually. Only its dynamic the ID of the video (boxvideo4) and the subclass in "box" (boxvideo1). The class is OK, but my code always generate "boxvideo4" as ID each time.

Comment: @Jose it does not make sense, "*I generate the content manually. Only its dynamic...*" this is a contradiction.

Comment: I dont know how explain this. I generate dynamically only ID and class, You can check it in my code js. classAdd, classCall and classCall2

Comment: @Jose you state you generate the code manually, so why are all the Divs the same ID?

Comment: NO. I didnt. `$('.servicios__layout .box .slider-video').attr('id', classCall2);` generate de ID, my issue it generates always the same ID. I generates always "boxvideo4"

Comment: @Jose it still does not make sense. I did update my answer to help address this based on your code.

Comment: I think the issue is that a missunderstand 'classCall2' <-- um that is a string, not a variable reference.... Thats why my code was working good changing dynamically the class but never change the ID.